# From a join table in MySQL, how to find all the foreign_key1 ids which have foreign_key2 assigned to them ONLY from given list?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have two tables. Table A and Table B. Both are connected with a many-to-many relationship.

```
Table A:

ID
---
1
2
3

Table B:

ID
---
4
5
6
7

Table AB:

ID | A_ID | B_ID
----------------
8  | 1    | 4
9  | 1    | 5
10 | 1    | 6
11 | 1    | 7
12 | 2    | 5
13 | 2    | 6
14 | 3    | 6
```

I want to find all Ids from table A, which have assigned Ids from table B from only given B Ids. For example here, we pass Ids in our queries - [5,6]
So it should return all A ids which have either all values from array [5,6] assigned or any no. of values but only from array. If other than array id is also assigned then don't include in result. Here result will be 2 and 3. ( 1 is not because it also has 4,7 assigned to it).
I am using Sequelize with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You need a sub select to omit unwanted `A_ID`. Playground: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/524468/3

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A_ID
FROM AB
WHERE B_ID IN (5, 6)
  AND A_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT A_ID
    FROM AB
    WHERE B_ID NOT IN (5, 6)
  )
```